# Can I use an array for ng-options instead of an object?

Tags: angularjs

If I have to use ng-options with a list instead of an object, how can I iterate over it ?

Here is the code for controller

```
  angular.module("mainapp")
  .controller('NewController', [ "$scope", function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {
    $scope.data = data;

    $scope.sex = ["Male", "Female"];

  }
]);
```

Here is the HTML5 code, which gives me error

```
<div ng-controller="New Controller">
    <label class="select">
    <select ng-model="sex" ng-options="for s in sex" >
    <option value="" selected="" disabled="">Sex</option>
    </select> <i></i> </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you actually want is something like this:

```
$scope.sex = ["Male", "Female"];
$scope.selection = "";

<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="s for s in sex">
```

[**Plunker Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jsSshZcEDDhCvmg3yWKC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

You are simply missing an s:

```
< ng-options="s for s in sex">
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/f9RSW/2/)

Suppose you have an array `records`:

```
 $scope.records = [{
        id: 1,
        value: "One",
    }, {
        id: 2,
        value: "Two",
    }, {
        id: 3,
        value: "Three",
    },{
        id: 4,
        value: "Four",
    }];
```

You can iterate over it using:

```
<select ng-options="record.id as record.value for record in records" ng-model="output">
    <option value = "">- Select -</option>
</select>
```

Basic syntax is: **record.desiredValueToSave as record.descriptionText for record in records**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DianaNassar/f9RSW/1/)**

Comment: Yes I can do it with an object but my question is it possible to iterate using list ?

Comment: What do you mean by a list? List of objects?